# Upload multiple files with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've developed a method to receive file(s) from a form and return information from each file after save the file. Probably there is one on the internet that does similar, but I didn't find, however I'm still learning c# and I like build some methods to help me.

I would like to post it with 2 propose, one is check if I did ok and another reason is to share the code.

Is there any suggestion?

If you like it! use it :)

I didn't have time to comment the whole code, sorry! :(

**METHOD**

```
        public String[,] upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> _files, List<string> _flSupportedTypes,int _flSizeLimit, string _serverPath)
        {
            /*
             * Array Details
             * 
             * { Fields detail } 
             * [1~] [0] - Status code
             *      [1] - Status message
             *      [2] - Upload file Name
             *      [3] - New file name
             *      [4] - Virtual Path
             *      [5] - Local Path
             *      
             * { General details }
             * [0]  [0] - Status Code 
             *      [1] - Status message
             *      [2] - total fields
             *      [3] - total fields processed 
             */
            int totalFieldsUpload   = _files != null ? _files.Count() : 0;
            int countFieldsUpload   = 0;
            int countFilesUpload    = 0;
            String[,] filesResult   = new String[totalFieldsUpload + 1, 6];

            if(totalFieldsUpload == 0)
            {
                filesResult[0, 0] = "0";
                filesResult[0, 1] = "No fields";
                filesResult[0, 2] = "0";
                filesResult[0, 3] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                filesResult[0, 0] = "1";
                filesResult[0, 1] = "OK";
                filesResult[0, 2] = totalFieldsUpload.ToString();

                if (!Directory.Exists(_serverPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(_serverPath);

                foreach (var file in _files)
                {
                    bool isContentOK = false;
                    countFieldsUpload++;

                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        String newfileName  = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc() +
                                              "_" + Path.GetRandomFileName() +
                                              "." + file.FileName.ToString().Split('.').Last();

                        String localPath    = _serverPath + newfileName;
                        String virtualPath  = localPath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], "~/").Replace(@"\", "/");

                        if (file.ContentLength <= _flSizeLimit)
                        {
                            foreach (var type in _flSupportedTypes)
                            {
                                if (file.ContentType == type)
                                {
                                    file.SaveAs(localPath);
                                    isContentOK = true;

                                    countFilesUpload++;

                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                    isContentOK = false;

                            }

                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 0] = "1";
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 1] = isContentOK ? "OK" : "ContentType Failed";
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 2] = file.FileName;
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 3] = newfileName;
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 4] = virtualPath;
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 5] = localPath;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 0] = "0";
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 1] = "Size Failed";
                            filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 2] = file.FileName;
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 0] = "0";
                        filesResult[countFieldsUpload, 1] = "Field empty";
                    }
                }

                filesResult[0, 3] = countFilesUpload.ToString();
             }

             return filesResult;              
        }
```

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionTest", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photo">Photo:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo[0]" id="photo_0">
        <input type="file" name="photo[1]" id="photo_1">
        <input type="file" name="photo[2]" id="photo_2">
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

**ACTION RESULT**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ActionTest(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> photo)
{
    List<string>    supportedTypes  = new List<string>() { "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png" };
    String          serverPath      = Server.MapPath("/") + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgTmpUploadPath"].ToString();
    String[,]       filesResult     = upload(photo, supportedTypes, 1048576, serverPath);

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read from `Request` object like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Page2(FormCollection objCollection)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {

         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

         ...
        }
    }
```